# How to formalize/organize a massive amount of eventHandler in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I am new to JavaScript and can't figure out how to code a massive amount of eventHandler, like `mouseover`/`mouseout`.

Imagine I have to type of elements on a page. Each element should trigger a specific event. Do I have to code every function for every element, or there is a way to abstract that so I they are generated by another function.

Here is an example with two lists of two elements, however I am thinking of the case of several hundreds of elements per list.

```html
<!-- List 1 -->
    <div id="a">the A</div>
    <div id="b">the B</div>
    <!-- List 2 -->
    <div id="i">the I</div>
    <div id="j">the J</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( '#a' )
        .mouseover(function() {
            $( '#i' ).css("color", "red")
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            $( '#i' ).css("color", "black")
        })

    $( '#b')
        .mouseover(function() {
            $( '#j' ).css("color", "red")
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            $( '#j' ).css("color", "black")
        })

    $( '#j')
        .mouseover(function() {
            $( '#a' ).css("color", "red")
            $( '#i' ).css("color", "red")
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            $( '#a' ).css("color", "black")
            $( '#i' ).css("color", "black")
        })
    </script>
```

How can I simply use an array like this, that represents the interaction I want :

```
var todo = [
    [a, [i]],
    [b, [j]],
    [j, [a, i]]
]
```

And a function that would implement them all at once :

```
makeAllMouseover(todo)
```

I guess I'm missing something pretty obvious about html/js but I couldn't figure out what/why...

Comment: Considering the amount of effort that's gone into multiple people answering this questions, I'm a bit surprised you've not commented, voted, or accepted any answer at all. A bit disappointing TBH!

Comment: I'm still experimenting the different answers :p. Given the amount of down votes, I'm a little bit lost about what to do...

Comment: Ignore the downvotes. Go with what suits you best. If you *need* your `todo` array for some reason then go with @JamieBarker answer. If you simply *thought* thats what you need but are happy to add some markup in your html instead go with mine. Both will work just fine though. All i'd say is dont go with the one which needed a `switch` and dont go with the one which loops over the entire array every time there is a mouseover/out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your `todo` array doesn't change format, the below should work dynamically with whatever you throw at it.

```js
var todo = [
  ['a', ['i']],
  ['b', ['j']],
  ['j', ['a', 'i']]
];

todo.forEach(function(el) { // Loop through the array
  $('#' + el[0]).hover(function() { // MouseIn 
    $('#' + el[1].join(', #')).addClass('makeRed'); // Stringify the targets to add the class
  }, function() { // MouseOut
    $('#' + el[1].join(', #')).removeClass('makeRed'); // Stringify the targets to remove the class
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  color: black;  
}

.makeRed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listContainer">
<!-- List 1 -->
<div id="a">the A</div>
<div id="b">the B</div>
<!-- List 2 -->
<div id="i">the I</div>
<div id="j">the J</div>
```

JamieC made a valid point about not using an ID for targetting event handlers. I would suggest going one step further and using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so only a single listener is added to the page, rather than multiple for each element:

```js
var todo = [
  ['a', ['i']],
  ['b', ['j']],
  ['j', ['a', 'i']]
];

function hoverText(id, isIn) {
  // Filter the array to just contain the one we've clicked
  var elements = todo.filter(function(value) {
    return id === value[0]
  })[0];

  // If the array is found, add/remove the class to/from the target elements
  if (elements) {
    elements = $('#' + elements[1].join(', #'));
     if (isIn) {
       elements.addClass('makeRed');
     } else {
       elements.removeClass('makeRed');
     }
   }
}

/**
 * Add event listener to the nearest element that surrounds all list items
 * Delegate the action to the list item(s).
 */
$('.listContainer').on('mouseenter', '.listItem', function(event) {
  hoverText(event.target.id, true)
}).on('mouseleave', '.listItem', function(event) {
  hoverText(event.target.id, false)
});
```

```css
.listContainer .listItem {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
}
.listContainer .listItem.makeRed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listContainer">
  <!-- List 1 -->
  <div class="listItem" id="a">the A</div>
  <div class="listItem" id="b">the B</div>
  <!-- List 2 -->
  <div class="listItem" id="i">the I</div>
  <div class="listItem" id="j">the J</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the negativity folks?

Comment: I dont know either, theres some weird voting going on in this question.

Comment: @mazieres I updated this answer with some of JamieC's helpful points from his answer, and expanded it to reduce the size of the potential memory allocation. I hope all (or some) of these _awful_ answers have helped you. ;)

Comment: Gosh this is such a terrible answer. It *really* deserves the downvotes it has. You've shown no effort *whatsoever*. ;)

Comment: Damn it you won! Consider yourself now my arch nemesis!

Comment: @Jamiec Pfft, why is everyone called Jamie such an arse? How ever will you cope without your precious 25 rep points? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would start off by not using id's for targetting event handlers - use a shared class, and I also would not use an array/map to represent your interaction. Its far easier to use some `data-*` attributes to represent your associations between elements

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- List 1 -->
    <div id="a" class="mouse-action" data-highlight="#i">the A</div>
    <div id="b" class="mouse-action" data-highlight="#j">the B</div>
    <!-- List 2 -->
    <div id="i" class="mouse-action">the I</div>
    <div id="j" class="mouse-action" data-highlight="#a, #b">the J</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(".mouse-action")
        .mouseover(function() {
            $( $(this).data("highlight") ).css("color", "red")
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            $( $(this).data("highlight") ).css("color", "black")
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Would love to know why the dv's here. This way is much easier, and Ive answered similar questions 10's of times before with this solution with good result.

Comment: Sorry, I was getting around to commenting, promise! This does the job, but it doesn't answer the OP's question of: "_How can I simply use an array like **this**, that represents the interaction I want_"

Comment: @JamieBarker if an amateur/newbie carpenter asks a professional how to bang a nail in with their shoe - the pro invariably points out a hammer, along with how to use it properly.

Comment: you make a valid point, but we can only guesstimate what the OP's **actual** objective is, and what their **actual** code is, as they've only given example data :/

Comment: I was probably harsh with my DV tbh, I reverted it. The post has helpful points for newbies, I just personally wouldn't answer a "data-driven" question with a "DOM manipulation" answer. It's just a bit like answering a question about react or angular with jQuery for me ;).

Comment: @JamieBarker thanks - this bit is the crunch for me `I guess I'm missing something pretty obvious about html/js` - they *were* missing something pretty obvious. This is a subset of the XY Problem (I think I need X to do Y).

Comment: I've expanded my answer with some of the helpful points you've made here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first of the following snippets to apply the effect you want to each one of the elements separately by yourself or, alternatively, you can use the second one which will do this for you automatically:

▶ **First Snippet:** *(applied to the first one)*

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function change(selector) {
  var affected, hoverColor;
  switch (selector) {
    case "#a":
      affected = ["#i"];
      hoverColor = "red";
      break;
    case "#b":
      affected = ["#j"];
      hoverColor = "blue";
      break;
    case "#j":
      affected = ["#a", "#i"];
      hoverColor = "yellow";
      break;
  }

  $(selector).hover(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < affected.length; i++) $(affected[i]).css("color", hoverColor)
  }, function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < affected.length; i++) $(affected[i]).css("color", "black")
  });
}

/* APPLY THE EFFECT */
change("#a");
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<!-- List 1 -->
<div id="a">the A</div>
<div id="b">the B</div>
<!-- List 2 -->
<div id="i">the I</div>
<div id="j">the J</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

▶ **Second Snippet:** *(applied to the every one)*

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
["#a", "#b", "#j"].forEach(function(each) {
  (function(selector) {
    var affected, hoverColor;
    switch (selector) {
      case "#a":
        affected = ["#i"];
        hoverColor = "red";
        break;
      case "#b":
        affected = ["#j"];
        hoverColor = "blue";
        break;
      case "#j":
        affected = ["#a", "#i"];
        hoverColor = "yellow";
        break;
    }

    $(selector).hover(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < affected.length; i++) $(affected[i]).css("color", hoverColor)
    }, function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < affected.length; i++) $(affected[i]).css("color", "black")
    });
  })(each);
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<!-- List 1 -->
<div id="a">the A</div>
<div id="b">the B</div>
<!-- List 2 -->
<div id="i">the I</div>
<div id="j">the J</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

▶ **Shorter code for the second script:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
["#a", "#b", "#j"].forEach(function(each) {
  (function(s) {
    var
      aff = (s === "#a") ? ["#i"] : ((s === "#b") ? ["#j"] : ((s === "#j") ? ["#a", "#i"] : "")),
      hovColor = (s === "#a") ? "red" : ((s === "#b") ? "blue" : ((s === "#j") ? "yellow" : "")),
      unhover;

    $(s).hover(changeColor, changeColor);
    
    function changeColor () {
      for (var i = 0; i < aff.length; i++) $(aff[i]).css("color", (unhover) ? "black" : hovColor);
      unhover = !unhover;
    }
  })(each);
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<!-- List 1 -->
<div id="a">the A</div>
<div id="b">the B</div>
<!-- List 2 -->
<div id="i">the I</div>
<div id="j">the J</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. For the **`affected`** variable, I'm using an array ***(`affected = ["#i"]`)*** instead of a string ***(`affected = "#i"`)***, so that we can take advantage of the **`length`** property of arrays and use a **`for`** loop to make sure that both elements of the third case get the desired effect.
2. Instead of using **`mouseover`** and **`mouseout`**, you can use **`hover`** which takes two arguments, both being functions and corresponding to **`mouseover`** and **`mouseout`** respectivelly ***(`hover(mouseover, mouseout)`)***.
3. The **`switch`** statement is hardcoded, which means that if you want to add more elements you have to create a new case for each one and, also, add the **`id`** of each element that you want to use **`hover`** on in the array preceding **`forEach`** in the beginning of the snippet.

Comment: The OP is asking to achieve interactions dynamically by simply supplying an array of data: "_How can I simply use an array like this, that represents the interaction I want_". Neither of your examples consume data to generate the interactions, and neither are dynamic. If the supplied data changed, you would then have to update the JavaScript code to match, and won't work with dynamic data such as a To-do list.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @JamieBarker. Your answer is better and indeed dynamic. I upvoted :)